# Can not explain ACL behavior

Tags: acl

So this is situation:
got server for web-developers. There are many developers. All `developers` + `PHP` + `Apache` belongs to `www` group. There is a development directory - `development`.

The goal is that every file in `development` directory has `755` permissions and whenever a any developer creates, modifies a file in `development` directory, files will still have `755`.

So I have read a number of `acl` tutorials, guides and howto's but I still can not get the result I want.

1. my disk is mounted with `acl`
2. I got `chown -R www:www development`
3. added `chmod g+s development`
4. I set a number of `acl` rules on `development` directory and got this:

   ```
   $ getfacl development
   # file: development
   # owner: www
   # group: www
   # flags: -s-
   user::rwx
   user:www:rwx
   group::rwx
   group:www:rwx
   mask::rwx
   other::r-x
   default:user::rwx
   default:user:www:rwx
   default:group::rwx
   default:group:www:rwx
   default:mask::rwx
   default:other::r-x

   p.s. I know its messy, was doing a number of tests
   ```
5. According to my idea of `ACL`, if directory had such rules, my task should be achieved, but when I try to create a file in `development` dir, I get:

   ```
   -rw-rw-r--+ 1 www     www      0 Nov 21 09:14 newfile
   ```

I can not seem to understand why it creates `rw-` instead `rwx`.

It is probably something simple that I missed or some general concept that I don't understand.

Comment: When you have ACL rules on a file, you should never use the permissions as reported by `ls`. ACLs override the basic file permissions. Use `getfacl` to view the permissions on the file.

Answer (score 4):

Your default ACLs replace the umask, which specifies not *default* permissions, but *maximum* permissions for creating new files.  In this case `rwxrwxr-x`.

Then your application calls `open` or `creat` with the permissions it wants.  Just about all applications will ask for `rw-rw-rw-` for files.

You can see this by running `strace`, e.g.

```
$ strace -e trace=file touch newfile
...
open("newfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```

(`0666` is the same as `rw-rw-rw-`.)

The two permissions are combined using bitwise AND to give `rw-rw-r--`.

```
  rwxrwxr-x     # default ACL
  rw-rw-rw-     # permission requested (e.g. by touch, vim, etc.)
& _________
  rw-rw-r--     # effective permissions
```

For another explanation, see [POSIX Access Control Lists](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher.pdf) — “Default ACL Example”.

So the real question is: why do you need the files to be executable?

Comment: Just tried `setfacl -m d:u::rwx,g::rwx,o:rwx .; touch beforeumask; umask 777; touch afterumask`.  Both get the same permissions.  So I'm pretty sure it *does* replace the umask.

Comment: You're right. I managed both to mess up my test and misread the manual. I've deleted my comment. Sorry.

Comment: `Your default ACLs replace the umask, which specifies not default permissions, but maximum permissions for creating new files.` Thanks.