# How can I cause cvs update to use the destination folder's default posix acl mask?

Tags: centos, acl, cvs

I have a directory and file with these permissions:

```
# file: blue/
# owner: user-a
# group: group-a
user::rwx
user:user-b:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:user-b:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: blue/bluer.php
# owner: user-a
# group: group-b
user::rw-
user:user-b:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

I run

```
cvs up -d /home/user-a/blue/bluer.php
```

and now the file has the following permissions

```
# file: blue/bluer.php
# owner: user-a
# group: group-b
user::rw-
user:user-b:rwx                #effective:r-x
group::rwx                     #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r--
```

According to [can not explain acl 
behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56278/can-not-explain-acl-behavior),
the running program has to ask for permissions explicitly.  How can I cause cvs update to use the destination folder's default acl mask?