# make ACL to work perfectly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, webserver, acl

I know there are plenty of questions and answers about ACL and permissions, but to be honest they are so weak to make any coherent understanding! it's just like a mix of unorganized information.

Hope this question will put an end to this confusion

**Problem**:

On my Ubuntu 14.04 web server, I want to:

- make all `files/future_files` with `640` permissions,
- all `folders/future_folders` with `750` permissions,
- AND make `Admin:www-data` the only *default owners*

**My solution:**

I used ACLs:

```
setfacl -Rdm u:admin:rwX /path/to/parent //capital X apply for folders
setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rX /path/to/parent
setfacl -Rdm o::- /path/to/parent
```

now already *existed* files and folders take the rules perfectly.

**Issue:**

Now I am logged as user `admin`, when I make new directory it gets `770` not `750`? And when I make new file it gets 660 not 640? Why isn't it adopting the rules!?

---

Here is `getfacl` output:

```
# owner: admin
# group: www-data
# flags: ss-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:admin:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:www-data:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

It looks like there is some conflict between rules! although I deleted all ACL before applying the new rules.

P.S. I remember combining them in one command like below used to work... but it's not!

```
etfacl -Rdm u:admin:rwX,g:www-data:rwX,o::- /path/to/parent
```

If you know a correct short version please don't hesitate to provide :)

Comment: Check `umask` for the user `admin`, it is having a default permission of `0022`. You can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution eventually, totally forgot to update it here
The solution is the following:

1: define owners for all and make owner group inheritable

```
- sudo chown -R admin:www-data /var/www/html 
- sudo chmod g+s  /var/www/html (inherit owner group)
```

2: apply default permission for folders and files (750 and 640 respectively; default is to be secured)

```
- sudo chmod -R 750 /var/www/html
- sudo find /var/www/html -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 640 (apply for files only)

** repeat file permissions for each sub-directory
```

3: apply permission for the writable files and folders

```
- sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/images
- sudo find /var/www/images -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 660
```

4: apply the auto inherit rules (ACL)

```
- setfacl -Rdm u::rwX,g::rwX,o::- /path/to/parent  (Capital X only apply to directories)
```

5: verify ACL:

```
- getfacl /var/www/html
```

Hope this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem and solution, expanding on the answer from @Engineeroholic

Here's what a possible problem might be

```
$ whoami
admin
$ umask
0000
```

`0000` is just a possible value -- one that you might see. Let us know what you *do* see.

Use one of the following options to fix it. I think this should fix your issue, even if the above doesn't end up being your problem.

```
# option 1: one session
$ umask 0027
```

or **(Make sure you append, `>>`. DON'T overwrite with a single greater-than sign.)**

```
# option 2: system-wide, note that you might need /etc/bash.profile, 
#           /etc/bash.bashrc, or something else called at login
#           if your system doesn't have /etc/.profile

$ echo -e "\n\n##New folders 0750, new files 0640" >> /etc/.profile
$ echo "umask 0027" >> /etc/.profile
$ source /etc/.profile
```

or **(Make sure you append, `>>`. DON'T overwrite with a single greater-than sign.)**

```
# option3: for `admin` only. Make sure that you are writing to 
#          a file called at login, in case ~/.bashrc isn't 
#          called at that point.

$ echo -e "\n\n##New folders 0750, new files 0640" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "umask 0027" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can create files that should have the permissions you want.

You will get what some people describe as `0770 - 0027 = 0750` where `0-7` goes to `0`.

More accurately, you have

```
   Octal1   Octal2   Binary1             Binary2
                       (    rwxrw---- )
      0770    0770         0111111000      0111111000
& NOT 0027  & 1750   & NOT 0000010111    & 1111101000
----------  ------   ----------------    ------------
      0750    0750         0111101000      0111101000
      ^                                 (   rwxr-x--- )
      |
      |
       `This one isn't really octal (I think.)
```

for your directories.

For your files:

```
  Octal     Binary1              Binary2
            (      rw-rw---- )
      0660        0110110000      0110110000
& NOT 0027  & NOT 0000010111    & 1111101000
----------    ----------------   ------------
      0640        0110100000      0110100000
                                (  rw-r----- )
```

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211485/291375) for more details.

I don't know that this answer elucidates the **cause** of the behavior, but it is a possible solution.

<s>Note that your `getfacl` includes `default:mask::rwx`, which you might change to `default:mask::r-x`, though that isn't likely the problem.</s>