# Why doesn't umask change execute permissions on files?

Tags: permissions, umask

If I change the `umask` to `0000`, I'd expect a text file to be created with `rwxrwxrwx` permissions (based on my understanding of the umask, [as described in the "possible duplicate" question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211481/how-umask-works)) However, when I try this, I get the following

```
$ umask 0000
$ touch /tmp/new.txt
$ ls -ld /tmp/new.txt 
-rw-rw-rw-  1 alanstorm  wheel  0 Jun  2 10:52 /tmp/new.txt
```

That is, execute permission is omitted, and I end up with `rw-rw-rw-` for files (directories are `rwxrwxrwx`).  I tried this on my local OS X machine, an old BSD machine I have at a shared host, and a linux server running on linode.

Why is this?  Its my understanding that umask is the final arbiter of permissions -- is my understanding of this incorrect?  If so, what else influences the default permissions of files on a unix system?

Comment: `umask does not specify the mode, it masks it. like when you mask something before painting. It dose not force the paint to land everywhere else, it only blocks it from landing where the mask is.

Comment: Note that if you're looking for a command that will leave the executable bits, the easiest way (in my opinion) is `$ umask 0000` ; `# no output` ; `$ touch /tmp/new.txt && chmod a+x /tmp/new.txt` ; `# no output` ; `$ ls -ld /tmp/new.txt` ; `-rwxrwxrwx 1 me my_group 0 Sep 18 18:29 /tmp/new.txt` `# <-output`

Comment: Related: [facl ignoring the "x" permission but only on files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/80216)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

umask is subtractive, not prescriptive: permission bits set in umask are removed by default from modes specified by programs, but umask can't add permission bits. `touch` [specifies mode 666 by default](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/touch.c#n135) (the link is to the GNU implementation, but others behave in the same way; this is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html)), so the resulting file ends up with that masked by the current `umask`: in your case, since `umask` doesn't mask anything, the result is 666.

The mode of a file or directory is usually specified by the program which creates it; most system calls involved take a mode (*e.g.* [`open(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), [`creat(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html), [`mkdir(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html) all have a mode parameter; but [`fopen(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) doesn't, and uses mode 666). Unless the parent directory specifies a default ACL, the process's umask at the time of the call is used to mask the specified mode (bitwise `mode & ~umask`; effectively this subtracts each set of permissions in umask from the mode), so the umask can only reduce a mode, it can't increase it. If the parent directory specifies a default ACL, that's used instead of the umask: the resulting file permissions are the intersection of the mode specified by the creating program, and that specified by the default ACL.

[POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_01_04) that the default mode should be 666 for files, 777 for directories; but this is just a *documentation* default (*i.e.*, when reading POSIX, if a program or function doesn't specify a file or directory's mode, the default applies), and it's not enforced by the system. Generally speaking this means that POSIX-compliant tools specify mode 666 when creating a file, and mode 777 when creating a directory, and the umask is subtracted from that; but the system can't enforce this, because there are many legitimate reasons to use other modes and/or ignore umask:

- compilers creating an executable try to produce a file with the executable bits set (they do apply umask though);
- [`chmod(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) obviously specifies the mode depending on its parameters, and it ignores umask when "who" is specified, or the mode is fully specified (so `chmod o+x` ignores umask, as does `chmod 777`, but `chmod +w` applies umask);
- tools which preserve permissions apply the appropriate mode and ignore umask: *e.g.* [`cp -p`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html), `tar -p`;
- tools which take a parameter fully specifying the mode also ignore umask: `install --mode`, `mknod -m`...

So you should think of umask as specifying the permission bits you don't want to see set by default, but be aware that this is just a request. You can't use it to specify permission bits you want to see set, only those you want to see unset. Furthermore, any process can change its umask anyway, using the [`umask(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) system call! The `umask(2)` system call is also the only POSIX-defined way for a process to find out its current umask (inherited from its parent). On Linux, starting with kernel 4.7, you can see a process's current umask by [looking for `Umask` in `/proc/${pid}/status`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3e42979e).

(For the sake of completeness, I'll mention that the behaviour regarding `setuid`, `setgid` and sticky bits is system-dependent, and remote filesystems such as NFS can add their own twists.)

Comment: It doesn't matter `touch` or other tools, that's behavior came from the `open()` syscall and the default file mode.

Comment: @cuonglm, there is no default file mode, if `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` is included in the `open()` flags, then the mode must be specified (see [the POSIX specification for `open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) or the [`open(2)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)). If you look at the source code I linked to, you'll see that `touch` specifies the mode.

Comment: Yes, there is. `777` for directory and `666` for file, you can read the link in my answer for more detail.

Comment: @cuonglm, seriously, there isn't, at least not for `open()`. Try a program running `open("somefile", O_CREAT);`, you'll get a file whose mode is whatever value was in memory on the stack — *e.g.* I got `--wsr-----` just now, with a umask of `022`. If you change the call to `open("somefile", O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);` you'll get an executable file (assuming your umask allows it).

Comment: @cuonglm I've clarified my answer; there is no default for `open()`, but there is one for `fopen()`.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt What about built-in redirection? (`echo a > f.txt`) It also seems to ignore executable bit.

Comment: @Thunderbeef POSIX doesn’t mention permissions for redirection explicitly, so the defaults apply: files are created with mode 666, masked by `umask`, so the executable bit can’t be set when a file is created using redirection. (If `f.txt` already exists and is executable, `echo a > f.txt` won’t change that.)

Answer (score 6):

The formula to calculate your file permission:

```
default_mode & ~umask
```

([Read the description of `O_CREAT` flag](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html#tag_16_357_03))

[Also specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_01_04), the default mode for file is `S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` or `666`, the default mode for directory is `S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO` or `777` if it was not specified by application.

Since when the execution bits in file default mode are `0`, perform bitwise AND `&` with `0` is always `0`.

That's why whatever value of `umask`, your newly created files will have execution bits off if your application don't specify the execution bits.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Run the `strace`, you can see the compiler call `chmod()` syscall, at least with `gcc`, `clang`.

Comment: I stand corrected, the compiler does indeed `chmod()`; but it is possible to create an executable using only an `open()` call.

Comment: Actually compiler behaviour depends on the linker; if you use `gold`, it [`open()`s the target file with the appropriate mode](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gold/output.cc;h=077e2c4481ecb8445028c773eba51506846e957e;hb=HEAD#l5062), it doesn't use `chmod()`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I think the reason gcc does a chmod at the end is that if the production of the file fails midway, it doesn't do the chmod, so you don't end up with an incomplete executable. You're perfectly right that it isn't because it can't: it could if it specified the execute bits in `umask`, like `mkdir` does.

Answer (score 2):

Above description is very good. It provides clear description of umask and permissions.
To be more pratical, If you want to see, what are permissions provided by "touch" do

" strace touch /tmp/new.txt "

observe the system call used by touch to create "new.txt"

for ex. o/p of "strace touch /tmp/new.txt"  (... -> some content)

...

open("/tmp/new.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3

...

for reference
[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)