# umask value not working

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

If I want a directory and file to have the permissions:

-rw-r---w-    -file

drwxr-x-w-    - directory

why doesn't my umask value of 024 work?

Comment: How do you create a file and directory, command?

Comment: What's the point of giving write  access to a directory without search access (for *others* in your `drwxr-x-w-`)?

Answer (score 1):

Files are typically created with permissions `rw-rw-rw-` (before the umask is applied), directories with permissions `rwxrwxrwx`. Since you want `rw-r---w-` and `rwxr-x-w-` respectively, you need to mask `----w-r-x`.

You can [set this using](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/umask.html)

```
umask 025
```

(set the mask as an octal value), or

```
umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=w
```

(set the *allowed* permissions in symbolic mode).

See [Why doesn't umask change execute permissions on files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287278/86440) for a discussion of default permissions.

Answer (score -1):

The default mask is `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx (octal 000)`

```
umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx    symbolic mode
umask 022     numeric mode
```

A numeric mask replaces the current file mode creation mask.  It is specified as an unsigned octal integer, constructed from the logical OR (sum) of the following mode bits (leading zeros can be omitted):

```
0400  ( a=rwx,u-r)  Read by owner
0200  ( a=rwx,u-w)  Write by owner
0100  ( a=rwx,u-x)  Execute (search in directory) by owner
0040  ( a=rwx,g-r)  Read by group
0020  ( a=rwx,g-w)  Write by group
0010  ( a=rwx,g-x)  Execute/search by group
0004  ( a=rwx,o-r)  Read by others
0002  ( a=rwx,o-w)  Write by others
0001  ( a=rwx,o-x)  Execute/search by others
```

To check umask value :

```
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

Comment: (1) This answer is little more than ‘‘RTFM’’, except you politely read the manual to the OP.  But it doesn’t really *answer* the question. (2) What do you mean by ‘‘A numeric mask replaces the current file mode creation mask.’’?